# Pabot slave cannot find chrome binary

Tags: jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I have created a pabot slave on jenkins which include python, Xvfb and chromedriver. But I try to run my scenario on that pod it give me error below. Even PATH has chromedriver directory.

```
webDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

---

Chrome driver is installed to /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Dockerfile;

```
FROM openshift/jenkins-slave-base-centos7:v3.11

USER root

#Install python
RUN yum update -y && yum install -y python3 xorg-x11-server-Xvfb

#Install requirements
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

#Chrome driver
COPY chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Pabot shell command;

```
cd test/TestCases/

Xvfb :99 &
export DISPLAY=:99

pabot --processes 1 --testlevelsplit --variable Browser:headlesschrome .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it says it can't find the Chrome binary, it's not talking about chromedriver. It's talking about the actual chrome browser. Those are two different things.

In addition to having the location of chromedriver on your PATH, you also need to have the location of chrome on your PATH. I don't know what's in the base docker image, but it might be that it doesn't have chrome installed.

Comment: I will try on server

Comment: @MustafaGüler: I recommend first just trying to run chrome on the server without robot to reduce the number of variables.